# When can we "multiply through" by the kernel of a homomorphism?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups, semidirect-product

Let $G/H=K$. I think I am right in saying that if $K\cong K'\trianglelefteq G$ and is such that $K'H=G$ and $K'\cap H=1$ then we have $H\times K'=G$. If we relax the normality requirement of $K'$ to simply $K'\le G$ we have $H\rtimes K'=G$. I think there is no need for Zappa-Szep products here.

Now there will be situations where I don't know whether the image is isomorphic to a subgroup or a normal subgroup, or if $K'\cap H=1$, or if $K'H=G$.

It has been pointed out in the comments that there is no general result for finding out the information about the image and kernel required to make a direct or semidirect product. What are some special cases? Finite abelian groups have been mentioned.

Comment: Note that in general $G/H$ is not actually a subgroup of $G$: it’s a set of cosets endowed with the induced multiplication. Rather, you need to find a subgroup $K$ of $G$ that is **isomorphic** to $G/H$.

Comment: Yes, I will edit the question. That's what I meant to say.

Comment: What you are asking for is rather difficult. Knowing that you have a subgroup isomorphic to a quotient is not an easy task for an arbitrary group, and even then you may have little control over how it interacts with the kernel of the quotient. E.g., if $G$ is a finite abelian group, then we know that for every subgroup $N$ there is a subgroup $K$ such that $K\con G/N$... but in general we don’t have any control about how $K$ interacts with $N$.

Comment: I guess then, that I am looking for special cases where we do know something,  such as finite abelian groups. I will make this clearer in the question.

Answer (score -1):

In general $G/H$ is not isomorphic to a subgroup of $G$.

For example, $G = (\mathbb Z,+)$ the group of integers, $H = (2\mathbb Z,+)$ the subgroup of even integers.  The quotient  $G/H$ has order $2$, so it cannot be a subroup of $G$.

Comment: I am aware of this. This is not what the question asks for. What I ask for is results which help classify images of homomorphisms. I.e. the question is "When is the image a subgroup, a normal subgroup, a subgroup with trivial intersection with the kernel? etc." Please see the question again.